# How to save multiple URLs as file per StartURL in scrapy - python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have the following code:

```
class VoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    def start_requests(self):

        self.start_url = [
            "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=1&getX=2",
            "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=2&getX=3",
            "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=3&getX=4",
            "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=4&getX=5"            
        ]

        for url in self.start_url:
            self.a = 0
            self.url = url
            self.page = self.url.split("/")[-1]
            self.filename = '%s.csv' % self.page
            with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write('URL:;'+self.url+'\n')

            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url,callback=self.parse,dont_filter = True)

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        votes = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"ratings")]/ul')

        with open(self.filename, 'a') as f:
            for vote in votes:
                self.a+=1
                f.write(str(self.a)+';'+vote.xpath('./li/text()').extract())

        if len(votes.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"next")]/@href').extract()) != 0:
            next_page = votes.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"next")]/@href').extract()[0]
            if next_page is not None:
                yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

My problem is, hat with this code everything will be saved in one file which in the example above will be:

```
URI.html?get=1&getX=2.csv
```

Since I run a loop over multiple URLs and create for each URL a new filename, I wonder what is wrong.

Why does this code not create new files per URL?

```
for url in self.start_url:
    self.a = 0
    self.url = url
    self.page = self.url.split("/")[-1]
    self.filename = '%s.csv' % self.page
    with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('URL:;'+self.url+'\n')
```

Can someone show me the right way/ example how I can save a file per start URL? Please consider, that I also want following pages appended into the file until there is no page to follow anymore.

**EDIT:**

The problem is not that files are not created. All the content of

```
with open(self.filename, 'a') as f:
            for vote in votes:
                self.a+=1
                f.write(str(self.a)+';'+vote.xpath('./li/text()').extract())
```

is saved into one file instead of into 4 files. All will be saved to the first available StartURL

**EDIT2:**

The idea is good! But from my example it doesn't work to replace:

```
file_name = '%s.csv' % response.url.split("/")[-1]
```

because the URI is changing and for every new URI is a new file created.

```
startURL 1     - "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=1&getX=2"
response.url 2 - "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=2&getX=2"
response.url 3 - "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=3&getX=2"
```

I just want to save everything in the startURL.

```
startURL 1     saved to "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=1&getX=2.csv"
response.url 2 saved to "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=1&getX=2.csv"
response.url 3 saved to "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=1&getX=2.csv"
```

a not reliable solution is to map the name by condition but it is not practical if the startURL amount is increasing or structure of the start URL changes:

```
if response.url.find("getX=2"):
    filename = self.start_url[0].split('/')[-1]
if response.url.find("getX=3"):
    filename = self.start_url[1].split('/')[-1]
if response.url.find("getX=4"):
    filename = self.start_url[2].split('/')[-1]
...
```

I don't understand why `self.filename` is not passed correct to `self.parse()`? Is there some multiprocessing so `self.filename` is always overwritten by the first item? How can i forward the correct filename without using the response object?

**SOLUTION:**

I pass the value via `request.meta`:

```
class VoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test2"

    def start_requests(self):

        self.start_url = [
            "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=1&getX=2",
            "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=2&getX=3",
            "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=3&getX=4",
            "http://www.domain.de/URI.html?get=4&getX=5"          
        ]

        for url in self.start_url:
            self.a = 0
            self.url = url
            self.page = self.url.split("/")[-1]
            self.filename = '%s.csv' % self.page
            with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write('URL:;'+self.url+'\n')
            request = scrapy.Request(url=self.url,callback=self.parse,dont_filter = True)
            request.meta['url'] = url
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        votes = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"ratings")]/ul')

        self.file = response.meta['url']
        filename = self.file.split("/")[-1]+'.csv'
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            for vote in votes:
                self.a+=1
                f.write(str(self.a)+';'+votes.xpath('./li/text()').extract()[0])

        if len(votes.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"next")]/@href').extract()) != 0:
            next_page = votes.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"next")]/@href').extract()[0]
            if next_page is not None:
                request = response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
                request.meta['url'] = self.file
                yield request
```

Comment: i run this code and it makes four `.csv` files

Comment: @zimdero Right! Thanks. I specified the issue in the edit - All following data after the header i created for the files is saved into one file instead over 4 files

Comment: ok i look in now

Comment: @zimdo it is a good idea, but it still doesn't work for my use case. Any other ideas or explanation? Thank you! I edited again

Comment: can you give me two urls ? to try it

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
with open(self.filename, 'a') as f:
    ...
```

try to use this, `file_name` will be the current `request.url` for example:  `URI.html?get=1&getX=2.csv`

```
file_name = '%s.csv' % response.url.split("/")[-1]
with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Your comment gave me the idea :) Thx for your efforts!

Comment: do you think I found a clean solution?